# Using Regex, select the leading slash but only when the string is 2 or more?

Tags: regex

I want to filter out all leading slashes unless the string is 1 character long. I am using Ruby 2.5.

- `/products/boxer` would match the first `/`
- `products/boxer` would not match anything
- `//products/boxer` would match the first two `//`
- `/` would NOT match the leading slash

My attempt as of now: `^[\/].{2,}$`

Test Strings:

```
/products/boxer
/products
/
//a
as/asdf
/
```

Thanks

Comment: Your current regex is selecting *everything* in a line/string (if the initial character passes), do you really want to match the line/string, or only the leading slash? Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to match?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I updated the question, thanks

Comment: @reid Please check my answer below.

Comment: Oh, you completely changed your question which makes my answer not applicable.

Comment: @KamilG. I noticed I should of been more clear. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^\/+(?! )
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of string.
- `\/+` One or more `/`.
- `(?! )` Negative lookahead. Ensure that whitespace does not follow.

You can try the regex live [here](http://rubular.com/r/K8BSAwDVgX).

Answer (score 1):

For the sample data you've provided use:

```
^(\/+\w+|\/{2,})$
```

Data:

```
/products/boxer
/products       <-- match
/
//a             <-- match
as/asdf
/
//              <-- match (additional to your data set)
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of the string
- `(` start of capturing group
- `\/+` matches one or more occurences of `/`
- `\w+` matches one or more character from `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- `|` OR operator
- `\/{2,}` matches two or more occurences of /
- `)` end of capturing group
- `$` end of the string

<kbd>**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCdV9t/4)**</kbd>

If you need, you can adjust the `\w` part to include other signs

Comment: Note: I'm a regex rookie. Anything you spot that might not be working please let me know.

Comment: You could simplify your expression. `{1,}` is `+` and there's no need to put `\w` in a character set.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness thanks for spotting that :-) I've included it in my explanation, but somehow left it untouched in the regex itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language, you're using, but this Works in JavaScript and C# when you set`multiline` to true:

```
^\/+(?=.+)[^\s]+\r?$
```

Explanation:

```
^\/+
```

will select all slashes from the start of the line.

```
(?=.+)
```

will look ahead for one or more extra characters.

```
[^\s]+
```

will select one or more characters not being White Space (to the end of the line).

You can test it [here](http://bak-o-soft.dk/RegEx/RegExBuilder.aspx)